# JQuery how to find and remove li element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm tryting to use the JQuery to find and remove the `<li>
    <a href="/arb/node/53/grouping/edit/">Edit group</a>
    </li>` with no luck at all.

Could please let me know to achieve this.

```
<ul class="tabs secondary">
<li class="active">
<a href="/arb/node/53/grouping">View</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/arb/node/53/grouping/add">Add new Group</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/arb/node/53/grouping/edit/">Edit group</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I try the following jquery, but it not work.

```
$(".tabs.secondary:contains(\"Edit group\")").remove()
```

The right solutions should be something that will find the word "Edit group" and remove it `<li>` parent.

Thanks

Finau

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("li:has('a'):contains('Edit group')").remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YqFfe/

Answer (score 7):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$('.tabs li:has(a[href="/arb/node/53/grouping/edit/"])').remove()
```

to remove it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4PkG/2/)

[reference](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Edit: since the number in the path is dynamic, you can probably use the following:

```
$('.tabs li:has(a[href$="/edit/"])').remove()
```

which will only remove the URL path that ends with `/edit/`.

[new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Agprx/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Edit Group') {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Edited to target text.

Comment: thanks Lazerblade for the response but that will not work.  /arb/node/53/grouping/edit/  the 53 is dynamic, it could be 5 or 10 ...

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try:

```
$('li:eq(2)').remove();

$('.tabs li:eq(2)').remove();
```